# Yet Another Reshaping Issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that is indexed over `status`, `date`. Most of the variables are specific for both `status` and `date`, but there is `superDuper` which is only specific for `date` and the same for each status:

```
                    t070199   t070299   t070201   t070105  superDuper  
date       status                                                       
2003-01-01 foo     0.137684  0.032750  1.729324  4.484633  481.329224   
           fubar   1.348261  0.000000  0.159443  0.636001  481.329224   
2005-01-01 foo     0.038752  0.006538  1.341507  3.518619  474.549400   
           fubar   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  8.457774  474.549400   
2007-01-01 foo     0.000000  0.097280  3.639593  1.901233  459.767016
```

If I do `df.unstack(level='status')`, I get something along the lines of

```
             t070199             t070299       superDuper             t070105  \
status           foo     fubar       foo fubar       foo     fubar       emp   
date                                                                           
2003-01-01  0.137684  1.348261  0.032750     0  1.729324  1.729324  4.484633   
2005-01-01  0.038752  0.000000  0.006538     0  1.341507  1.341507  3.518619   
2007-01-01  0.000000  0.000000  0.097280     0  3.639593  3.639593  1.901233   
2009-01-01  0.010630  0.000000  0.000000     0  1.840457  1.840457  2.728080   
2011-01-01  0.013474  0.000000  0.000000     0  2.020553  1.739148  1.320693
```

That is, there is a first level containing the columns `txxxx`, `superDuper`, and for each, we have two sub columns for the two columns.

I would like to reshape the data such that I have the following first level columns:

```
[`t070199`, `t070299`, `t070201`, `t070105`]
```

And for each of these top level columns, I would like to have 3 sub columns:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'superDuper']
```

And then as the index, only `date`. Since `superDuper` is not specific to the `txxxx` columns, this probably implies repeating that column. `pivot` doesn't get me there, and since it is not a sublayer, `unstack()` probably doesn't do the trick either. What is an approach I could try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with your dataframe:

```
                    t070199   t070299   t070201   t070105  superDuper
date       status                                                    
2003-01-01 foo     0.137684  0.032750  1.729324  4.484633  481.329224
           bar     1.348261  0.000000  0.159443  0.636001  481.329224
2005-01-01 foo     0.038752  0.006538  1.341507  3.518619  474.549400
           bar     0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  8.457774  474.549400
2007-01-01 foo     0.000000  0.097280  3.639593  1.901233  459.767016
```

Pop out `superDuper` and save for later.  Now you can use unstack.

```
>>> sd = df.pop("superDuper")
>>> df = df.unstack()
             t070199             t070299             t070201            \
status           bar       foo       bar       foo       bar       foo   
date                                                                     
2003-01-01  1.348261  0.137684  0.000000  0.032750  0.159443  1.729324   
2005-01-01  0.000000  0.038752  0.000000  0.006538  0.000000  1.341507   
2007-01-01       NaN  0.000000       NaN  0.097280       NaN  3.639593   

             t070105            
status           bar       foo  
date                            
2003-01-01  0.636001  4.484633  
2005-01-01  8.457774  3.518619  
2007-01-01       NaN  1.901233
```

Get us the unique `superDuper` values:

```
>>> sd = sd.reset_index(level="status", drop=True).drop_duplicates()
date
2003-01-01    481.329224
2005-01-01    474.549400
2007-01-01    459.767016
Name: superDuper, dtype: object
```

Now, I'm going to assume you *want* a `superDuper` sub-column for each txxxx.  It isn't really clear from your question whether that's true or you're just resigned to it.

You can use a dict comprehension to get the new columns.

```
>>> new = pd.DataFrame({(col, sd.name): sd for col in
                  df.columns.get_level_values(0)})

               t070105     t070199     t070201     t070299
            superDuper  superDuper  superDuper  superDuper
date                                                      
2003-01-01  481.329224  481.329224  481.329224  481.329224
2005-01-01  474.549400  474.549400  474.549400  474.549400
2007-01-01  459.767016  459.767016  459.767016  459.767016
```

Now just join and sort:

```
>>>df.join(new).sort(axis=1)
             t070105                         t070199                        \
status           bar       foo  superDuper       bar       foo  superDuper   
date                                                                         
2003-01-01  0.636001  4.484633  481.329224  1.348261  0.137684  481.329224   
2005-01-01  8.457774  3.518619  474.549400  0.000000  0.038752  474.549400   
2007-01-01       NaN  1.901233  459.767016       NaN  0.000000  459.767016   

             t070201                         t070299                        
status           bar       foo  superDuper       bar       foo  superDuper  
date                                                                        
2003-01-01  0.159443  1.729324  481.329224  0.000000  0.032750  481.329224  
2005-01-01  0.000000  1.341507  474.549400  0.000000  0.006538  474.549400  
2007-01-01       NaN  3.639593  459.767016       NaN  0.097280  459.767016
```

Comment: Very interesting answer, that also helped me with some new commands. I forgot it, but I was also stumbling over a `df.columns` method that swaps the levels given an order. That might make it a bit simpler after `unstack()`.